# When I delete my own down-voted question, don't I get my lost reputation back?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

When I delete my own down-voted question, don't I get my lost reputation back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you get your reputation back but it wont be updated immediately. To check this, you can go to `/reputation` page and trigger recalc. Or wait for the system to recalc until you get your lost reputation back.

Comment: Note that the total as shown in /reputation will be the new total you'll get when you trigger the recalc. This might be lower after all.

Comment: (As an aside: I always thought that when deleting your own posts, reputation would be returned right away. But I don't know why I thought that.)

Comment: @Arjan - The lost reputation is returned immediately on `/reputation` page but not in the user profile on site. It updates immediately only when it is through up/down votes (cancelled), not when posts get deleted. ;)