# Does deleting your own question remove the down vote effect on your reputation?

Tags: support, down-votes, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I delete my own down-voted question, don't I get my lost reputation back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83549/when-i-delete-my-own-down-voted-question-dont-i-get-my-lost-reputation-back)

If a question I posted with many down votes is deleted, does that cause me to regain the lost reputation due to the many down votes on that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will if you trigger a [reputation recalc](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), yes.

However the down-votes still count towards [a ban for asking too many poor-quality questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this).

Comment: But, if your question has any answers, you cannot delete it.